# C# Unity ¿OnCollisionEnter disminuye performance si se actualiza constantemente?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity

verán quiero hacer un ataque de área, es decir, el personaje salta y al colisionar contra el suelo se ejecuta la "explosión".

**Contexto de mi código:** Tengo una variable bool `isOnGround` que declaro globalmente como true porque ya empezaría en suelo, cuando salta `isOnGround = false` y cuando el player cae y colisiona con el collider del suelo `isOnGround = true`

Mi duda/problema:
Quiero saber si esto genera una disminución del performance, ya que al estar en el suelo siempre va a estar llamándose al método OnCollisionEnter, donde pregunto si player colisiona con el suelo, en caso de que colisione `isOnGround = true`, entonces como siempre esta colisionando hasta que salta, va a estar siempre pasándole el valor de true a `isOnGround` quiero saber si esto es así y como lo solucionaría.
Les dejo mi código hermanos.

**OnCollisionEnter**

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && currentePowerUp == PowerUpType.Pushback)
    {
        Rigidbody enemyRb = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        Vector3 awayFromPlayer = collision.gameObject.transform.position - transform.position;

        enemyRb.AddForce(awayFromPlayer * powerupStrength, ForceMode.Impulse);

        Debug.Log($"player collides with {collision.gameObject.name} with the powerup set to {currentePowerUp.ToString()}");
    }
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {

      isOnGround = true;

    }

}
```

**SmashAttack**

```
void SmashAttack()
{
    if (isOnGround)
    {
 playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * 20, ForceMode.Impulse);
    isOnGround = false;

        
    
    }
   

    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 5f);

    foreach (Collider c in colliders)
    {

        if (c.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {

            Vector3 away = (transform.position - c.gameObject.transform.position).normalized;

            c.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(-away * powerupStrength, ForceMode.Impulse);

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los colliders en unity tienen 6 eventos, 3 para colisiones y 3 para triggers.

- **OnCollisionEnter**. Se llama cada vez que el collider comienza el contacto con otro.
- **OnCollisionExit**. Se llama cada vez que el collider finaliza el contacto con otro.
- **OnCollisionStay**. Se llama una vez por cuadro para cada collider con el que esté en contacto.

Si se encuentra en modo trigger, se llaman a las funciones `OnTriggerEnter, OnTriggerExit y OnTriggerStay` de manera análoga a las recién vistas.

Lo lógico es que si el suelo es un solo objeto y no hay más colisiones, no tengas problemas de rendimiento.

Recuerda que para saber si el jugador dejó de estar en el suelo puedes usar **OnCollisionExit** del mismo modo que haces con **OnCollisionEnter**.

```
private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGround = false;
    }
}
```

También quiero mencionar que, al se un solo objeto el que estás recibiendo en estas funciones, éste será una cosa o la otra, no ambas. Entonces puedes cambiar el `if` por un `else if` y le quitas la carga de verificar una condición si la otra se cumple.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && currentePowerUp == PowerUpType.Pushback)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isOnGround = true;
    }
}
```

Como último detalle, quiero mencionar que esta línea de código no es necesaria:

```
Rigidbody enemyRb = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

Puesto que `Collision` te brinda una forma más sencilla de obtener el `Rigidbody`, así:

```
Rigidbody enemyRb = collision.rigidbody;
```

También te dejo la documentación oficial para que la consultes:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html